# getting average hours in power BI

Tags: powerbi

How to convert below to hours in power BI, it's giving more than 60 minutes in BI it's not converting to hours after reaching more than 60 minutes. example total is 96 minutes wherein it should be 1:36 .

```
Row Labels   Average of open hrs 
Call Center      0.13 
Central-1        1.99 
Central-2        1.83 
East             2.71 
North            2.26 
South            3.03 
West             1.06 
Grand Total      0.96
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the duration as a float, you can write a measure to display hours and minutes something like this:

```
Duration = 
var hours = sum(Table1[hours])
var wholeHours = floor(hours,1)
var minutes = 60 * ( hours - wholeHours )
return  wholeHours & ":" & FORMAT(minutes,"00")
```